# How many displays/monitors can a Mac Mini 2020 M1 support?

Tags: display, mac-mini

How many displays/monitors can a Mac Mini 2020 M1 support? There are 2 USB4 ports and one HDMI.

Don't count DisplayLink and AirPlay displays.

Comment: Is this a thought exercise or are you trying to solve an actual problem?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, because searching through those sources I could find similar questions. No, because this is a StackExchange question and if those indicated websites will disappear then this question will stay without response.